# Why am I outside the <Router> after rendering inside it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Im building a Reactjs App. I don't understand why doing this is wrong and lead me to this error :

> `Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Redirect> outside a <Router>`

Here is the code :

A simple router in index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={(props) => <AppContainer><HomePage {...props}/></AppContainer>}/>
            <Route exact path="/register" component={(props) => <AppContainer><RegisterPage1 {...props}/></AppContainer>}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The AppContainer is just a simple div with id :

```
export default function AppContainer({children}) {
    return (
        <div id="appContainer">{children}</div>
    );
}
```

Inside RegisterPage1, I trigger a Render on "appContainer" after some process. This should render a new component inside the router.

```
ReactDOM.render(<RegisterPage2 data={res}/>, document.getElementById('appContainer'));
```

Inside RegisterPage2, I'm using  and I get the above error.

```
if (redirectHome) return (<Redirect to={"/"}/>)
else {
    return (
//RegisterPage2Components
    )
}
```

Since I'm rendering inside the Router, I dont understand why I can use Redirect in RegisterPage1 and cannot in RegisterPage2. I checked in RegisterPage2 and the router is still here (by adding some random text between the Router and the Switch).
If rendering like this is wrong, what is the correct way without adding a new route ?

Codesandbox :
https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-leftpad-7s5sy?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Why is `RegisterPage2` being rendered by ReactDom and not the react app? Seems to me it is possible you've multiple instances of React running your app if `RegisterPage2` is imported elsewhere and "injected" into *some* DOMNode that also happens to be a running react app. Can you produce a *running* codesandbox with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since I'm rendering inside the Router, I dont understand why I can use
> Redirect in RegisterPage1 and cannot in RegisterPage2.

React Dev Tools can help you here

[image]

As you can see at the bottom part of the image, `RegisterPage2` is not inside a Router component. Compare it with the topmost portion of the image, that React App is wrapped inside a `BrowserRouter`. You will realize why these errors occur.

> If rendering like this is wrong, what is the correct way without
> adding a new route?

It is with great difficulty this requirement you are asking. It will be hard to traverse between two React Apps using `react-router` if they don't have a common Router parent. I suggest you resort to the classic server side http request (example anchor tags or `window.href.location`) instead of using Single Page Application technologies for this feature you are developing

Answer (score 0):

That issue is cause by this line

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <RegisterPage2 data={res}/>,
    document.getElementById('appContainer')
);
```

This line is supposed to render the `RegisterPage2` component as the **Root component** of your React app.

And in the `RegisterPage2` you are using `Redirect` by assuming the `RegisterPage2` has already a parent component which has already use the `react- router-dom` `Router` Component. Because It's render as the Root Component without is beeing wrap in the `Router` Component that is the reason you are getting that error.

Comment: When I'm on the RegisterPage2, I can still see the "This is the Router" sentence, between the <Router> and the <Switch>. Does it no  mean that the Router is still here ? How shall I render RegisterPage2 otherwise ? Is a nested second router the only solution ?